# Lazy load image if image at server is changed

Tags: android, server, android-recyclerview, image-loading

I am working on android project in which I have to load images from server into recycler view. I am currently loading all the images once the app is started. But I want to load image if and only if the image at server is changed. Is this possible? Just put me in correct path.

Comment: You could ask the server for a hash of the image and compare hashes locally. If they differ ask for the image.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any library for that? Or do I need to develop it myself?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, that's just the obvious logical solution to your problem. Off the top of my one approach is to configure a php script to compute and serve the hash of the image on the server. Then all you're doing in java is an http(s) request and an integer/string comparison, and depending on inequality actually fetching said image.

Comment: You are very welcome. Good luck with your app!

Comment: Another option might be have an LRU cache of images along with their last modified date/time.  Then you request the image with If-Modified-Since header.  The server will return a 304 if the image hasn't been updated.  A little easier than a dedicated hash function.

Comment: I have not worked with that LRU cache. But thanks, I will learn and use it